# How can I make a communication exclusively trusted between mobile/web clients and back-end?

Tags: spring, web-services, security, ssl, mobile

I have a mobile and web application to stream music. Here is my actual architecture:

- RESTful service (Spring Boot)
- Spring Security
- OAuth2
- HTTPS with domain certificated by CA

The questions is:
**How can I make a communication exclusively between my mobile clients and back-end?** (same thing between web client and back-end)

My suggestion is to split the problem in two parts - create **two web services**:

1. One back-end for mobile apps (without CRSF protection) with user certificate.
2. One back-end for web player (with CRSF protection) accepting requests only from web player's domain.

---

For mobile problem,

I'm able to intercept my mobile requests via proxy using Fiddler, decrypting HTTPS and getting important information like URL, headers, tokens.

But I know that there is an approach to avoid it making requests rejected when intercepted by another CA, like a exclusively trusted communication between back-end and mobile apps. How can I do that for mobile solution?

---

For web player problem,

he problem is bigger because browser will show headers, urls and tokens to anyone.

As I can't hide these information like mobile app do, I could make my back-end accept requests only from web player's domain. What is the best solution for this case?

---

**UPDATED**

Decompile mobile client is simpler than I imagined. As I can't protect/ofuscate keys, tokens and urls, my suggestion is **to limit requests per user's token on back-end**. But how can I do that on web player? I have the same token for anyone (no user's authentication).

I found this documment about decompile mobile clients.
http://pt.slideshare.net/denimgroup/developing-secure-mobile-applications-17732256

Comment: You cannot control the client. Someone can always decompile your client and make whatever changes they want.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, you are right, I updated my question with a new suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [asymmetric cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). You request a public key from a server, and encrypt all following communication with it. And only your back-end will understand what you are sending to it, because only it has a private key to decrypt a message.

> Note that your users still will be able to extract unencrypted data
> directly from client memory. And you have no real way to disallow this!